# The summer term exams must go on

Tags: visual, knowledge, science

The staff at **Farthingbottom School** are in a bit of a fix: the summer term exams are due to start soon, but the exam papers haven't arrived yet.

Dr Linnaeus (the Head of Biology) takes care of everything every year, but a couple of weeks ago he was taken seriously ill and
he's still lying unconscious in hospital. Nobody knows if the papers have even been sent to the printers yet, or which printers are supposed to be dealing with them. All the details are on Dr Linnaeus' computer. Of course, nobody knows his password.

All the staff have to go on is the blackboard in his study and a comment during a discussion on passwords in the staff room some time ago where he mentioned that he favours those that are 20 characters long.

[image]

**Question:** Can you work out the password?

Comment: May you give us an additional hint? I've been investigating every image for nearly an hour and a half, but can't find a pattern.

Comment: Is the red arrow saying we should start with image 6? Or is it simply pointing the shadow? Doesn't this shadow suspiciously remind us of the dog in image 7?

Comment: @joselopez The teachers don't believe that the shadow is relevant.

Comment: Does the name of the school (farthingbottom) have something to do with it?

Comment: @Anna No - this is the latest in a series of puzzles based in a fictional school. The name of the school was only relevant in one of them: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20589/whos-been-stealing-my-h

Comment: is there any relevant information in one of the other puzzles then? Do I have to have seen the other puzzles to be able to solve this one?

Comment: @Anna No, everything required for the puzzle is on this page and they are all different.

Comment: Hey Gordon. Are you sure this puzzle is solvable without needing extra hints? Because everything is so abstract right now. Please, give hints or additional information.

Comment: @JoseLopez As the puzzle was posted less than 24 hours ago, I'd rather wait and see how people progress without further clues. Someone who hasn't seen it yet might come on and solve it. If there is no progress by this time tomorrow, I might add a hint.

Comment: My question is: is this puzzle realistically solvable without the help of hints? For example, do we need to investigate about each of the 4 humans in the image (Peter Sellers, Maurice Tillet, ...)? Or everything is in the image without need to investigate further?

Comment: @joselopez The answer below from Gordon Allocman has already provided all the detail required for the puzzle regarding those 4 people.

Comment: @JoseLopez This puzzle has the "Knowledge" tag.  You're going to need knowledge about some of the things in the puzzle.  How you come across that knowledge is up to you.  Sometimes, people just know it, sometimes they do research.  These are puzzles some are small, some are big, some are easy, some are hard.  Just be patient and calculating.  If a hint is required, it will appear after the asker has determined that one is needed because activity has died down.  Ultimately, good luck!

Comment: Hey @LeppyR64, I'm new here and didn't notice the "Knowledge" tag. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Hey @GordonK, thank you for this awesome puzzle. Please, keep them coming!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Password:**

> Paracanthurushepatus (Paracanthurus hepatus)

**Overall question details:**

> The professor is Dr. Linnaeus better known as [Carl Linnaeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Linnaeus) who is known for his creation of Index Cards (likely not important for this puzzle) and his creation of the [Linnaeus Taxonomy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linnaean_taxonomy) Based on the fact that the white board says "My Family" and most of the images are of animals, I believe taxonomy (more specifically the families) are important for this puzzle

**Images (listed in order shown on the board (number refers number shown on the picture)):**

**9:**

> [Cetomimidae a.k.a Flabby whalefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cetomimidae), family = Cetomimi[d]ae

**2 (listed in order from top left to bottom right (across then down)):**

**2.1:**

> [Columbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo)(character)/[Peter Falk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Falk)(actor)

**2.2:**

> [Hercule Poirot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercule_Poirot)(character)/[Sir Peter Ustinov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Ustinov)(actor)

**2.3:**

> [Inspector Clouseau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspector_Clouseau)(character)/[Peter Sellers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Sellers)(character)

**2.4:**

> Trunk a.k.a. an elephant nose

**Which together might mean:**

> All actors named Peter then an elephant nose => [Peters' Elephantnose Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peters%27_elephantnose_fish), family = M[o]rmyridae

**4:**

> [Queen Parrotfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_parrotfish), family = Sca[r]idae

**11:**

> [Crocodile Icefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channichthyidae), family = Channichth[y]idae

**1:**

> [Pearlside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurolicus), family = [S]ternoptychidae
>  OP's intended fish: [Round Whitefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_whitefish), family = [S]almonidae

**5:**

> Zebra stripes and map is of Turkey, so a [Zebra Turkeyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrochirus_zebra) family = Scor[p]aenidae

**8:**

> [Goatfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goatfish) fish that can change their color (maybe to white and blue), family = Mullida[e]
>  OP's specific goatfish: Bicolor Goatfish (same family)

**3:**

> This is an [Upside-down Catfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upside-down_catfish) ignoring the Asian upside-down catfish, they all share the same family = Mo[c]hokidae

**10:**

> This is an image of [Maurice Tillet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_French_Angel) known as the french angel => [French Angelfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_angelfish) family = Pomacanth[i]dae

**7:**

> [Black Dogfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_dogfish), family = Etmopt[e]ridae
>  OP's intended fish: [Broadbanded Lanternshark (a.k.a dogfish)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_whitefish), same family

**6:**

> [Southern Sandfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_sandfish) which lives off the coast of Australia/New Zealand (hence the kangaroo), family = Lepto[s]copidae

**Pattern:**

> All of the clues are types of fish

**Next Step:**

> Take the letter at the specified number of each fish's family in order shown on the blackboard and you get DORYSPECIES. Dory from Finding Nemo is a royal blue tang which the species name is Paracanthurus hepatus, which contains 20 characters

**Footnote:** @Neon612 helped find a bunch of the clues

Comment: I am sure number 5 is also a map! What do you think?

Comment: @JoseLopez I hadn't thought about that, I will look a little more into that

Comment: Other thing I thought, with respect image number 7. The words "Bend" and "100gb caps" are in orange. Maybe "Bend" refers to any of the animals that are bent over (like the goat or the kangaroo?), "100" is the number "4" in decimal, "gb" is an abbreviation for "Great Britain" (Peter Sellers is from GB; the other two are asians btw!) and "caps" maybe refers to those wearing a cap (i.e. Peter Sellers and the parrot!). Hidden message?

Comment: Another thing I thought, is the relation between number 9 (obese dolphin) and number 10 (acromegaly). Coincidence?

Comment: I believe #4 may be a [King Parrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_king_parrot)?

Comment: Good point feelinferrety!

Comment: w&b could mean white and black/brown/blue

Comment: #2 are all actors named Peter (also if the elephant is Jumbo/Dumbo all the names rhyme...), #7 I wouldn't read too much into the orange text as its just the standard logo, #10 I think he was known for his bearhug as a wrestler

Comment: @GordonAllocman I would have never said number 5 is the map of Turkey! How did you find out? There were a lot of possibilities!

Comment: Bravo! I loved it.